# Sessão PHP expira antes do tempo

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Estou com um problema a um tempo de sessão no PHP com CodeIgniter. Eu estava usando as sessões no CI e com tantos problemas resolvi procurar uma solução para usar sessões nativas com o CI e a principio já melhorou, mas ainda assim continua caindo a sessão antes do tempo pré determinado.

Nas configurações eu deixei setado o `sess_expiration` com 7200 (valor padrão do CI) e sempre que fico sem mexer no sistema por um determinado tempo (já fiz vários testes como 10min, 30min, 1h) e quase sempre cai quando vou atualizar a página.

Joguei o código no Pastebin para ficar mais fácil a leitura do mesmo.

http://pastebin.com/aq6tfdnM

E inspecionando o firebug, no Resouces->Cookies o Expires / Max-Age teoricamente esta correto.
[image: print do firebug]

Comment: As configurações de data e timezone do seu servidor estão corretas? Repare que as sessões já estão expiradas (25 de Fevereiro) se considerarmos a data de hoje (23 de Julho)

Comment: Sim @gmsantos ... se vc perceber quando eu fiz essa pergunta, foi em 25 de fevereiro mesmo.. Mas detalhe, ainda tenho problemas com sessões no CI....

Comment: Não notei esse detalhe, pensei que era uma pergunta recente

Answer (score 1):

Tens aqui a minha função de sessão:

```
function sessionTimeout($time_out)//em minutos
{
    $time_out= 60*$time_out;//passa para segundos

    ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', $time_out);

    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > $time_out)) 
    {
        // último pedido foi a mais de $time_out atrás
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    }
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // atualiza a hora da última atividade

    if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
    } else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > $time_out) 
    {
        // sessão começou a mais de $time_out atrás
        session_regenerate_id(true);    // muda o ID de sessão para a atual sessão e invalida o antigo ID de sessão
        $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // atualiza altura que a sessão foi criada
    }
}
```

Baseado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/1817673) do SOEN.

Comment: Por algum motivo, talvez o mesmo que o do AP, acontece me o mesmo. Sem conseguir resolver até agora.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta ir lá no codeigniter application\config\config.php e alterar esses valores

```
$config['sess_expiration']= 0; /* nunca expirar a sessão sózinha  */
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE; /* finalizar sessão quando o navegador for fechado */
```

ou você pode tentar pelo .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime "99999999"
```

http://www.kinghost.com.br/wiki/doku.php/htaccess

Comment: Então, deixei aberto a página por um tempo sem mexer e depois de 1h fui atualizar e ainda assim me derrubou. Se eu deixar a `sess_expiration` igual a zero na prática vai setar para 2 anos `(60*60*24*365*2)` e o `sess_expire_on_close` não é utilizado na classe que mostrei. Tem mais alguma ideia de como posso fazer?

Comment: @MarceloDiniz fiz uma alteração na resposta...

Comment: então, ainda nada, demorei para responder pois deixei em testes. Já tem um tempo que estou tentando resolver esse problema e não esta nada fácil. Imagino que não seja algo com configuração de servidor pois já testei em 3 diferentes e acontece a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu cansei de ter problema com a library session do CodeIgniter.
Por isso eu desenvolvi a minha baseada na Session Nativa do PHP e nunca tive problema.

Eu abri um projeto no GitHub, segue o link:
https://github.com/alamops/codeigniter_native_session

- Só usar como uma library qualquer do CodeIgniter
- Qualquer implementação ou erro, só enviar um Pull Request ou abrir uma Issue

Comment: Então, eu tbm estou meio cansado de ter problemas com as Sessões do CI, tanto que já procurei outras libraries que implementavam as sessões nativas do php e ainda assim davam algum problema. Depois vou dar uma olhada melhor nessa sua. Valew

Comment: Ok, beleza.
Eu havia feito um teste na biblioteca nativa do CodeIgniter, e o cookie não salva.
Daí resolvi desenvolver a minha mesmo, baseada na native session com as principais funções que o CodeIgniter oferece.